# Апк с ярлыком

Tags: apk, android

Здравствуйте, скажите, пожалуйста, как создать апк, при установке которого бы на главном экране появлялся ярлык?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) при установк**Е**.  
2) Никак. при установке APK **невозможно** выполнить какой-либо код из него. Можно только, например, [при первом запуске](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+create+shortcut+of+my+app)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только что узнал, что если мы устанавливаем приложение из Google Play, то ярлык ставится сам при установке.

Comment: @Welgum, ровно до тех пор, пока это не отключить в настройках Google Play